# Insert New Row with Sequential Number after criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

I will admit to being a terrible at code, and have always struggled with Macros...  forgive my ignorance.

What I am working on building is a part number index that will create a new sequential number within a numerical series after a macro-button is pressed.

I'd like each button to scan between  a range [i.e. 11-0000 (MIN) and 11-9999 (MAX)] and select the max value cell that exists. At that selection point insert an entire new row below with the next + 1 sequential number in the "B" column.

I have my button creating the table row as I would like, however I need help in defining the *".select(=Max(B:B))"* and as I understand Max will also limit the # of line items it queries?
I have also been playing with *.Range("B" & Rows.CountLarge)* with little to no success.

Ideally the 11-**** button [as seen in the screen cap] should insert a sequential number below the highlighted row.

Maybe I'm way over my head, but any guidance even in approach or fundamental structure of the code would help be greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Sheets("ENGINEERING-PART NUMBERS").Range("B" & Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

  ActiveCell.Value = "=ActiveCell + 1"

End Sub
```

[Screen Cap of Spread Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBKbb.png)

Comment: I don't know what `CountLarge` is doing, but for the last row in column B with info, you can do `Sheets("X").Range("B"&rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` ...your whole code can be greatly reduced - `Sheets("XYZ").Range("B"&rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Insert` Then add the value in the offset cell.

Comment: is 11-000 just a format or the cell actually does have a combination of two digits, a dash and four digits?

Comment: Your parts list looks like a table (list object). Is it that? If so, why don't you create separate tables, one under the other on the same tab, for each group? That would save a lot of code. And, yes, please do tell us the *NumberFormat* applied to the part number. *Right-click > Format Cells > Number tab*. Ideally, there should be a *Custom* format like *00\-0000*. If you have a text format, enter *110000* in the cell and apply the *Custom* format I have suggested. That would further reduce the amount of code you need.

Comment: Wow, what a tremendously helpful community, Thank You in advance -  11-0000 or 22-0000 is just a number format (really only the last 4 digits would change/sequence).  I was using a table and had much more complex code that I didn't fully understand.

Comment: @Variatus - I had been avoiding the use of separate tables in order to be able to search/index/sort "everything" as opposed to having separate areas to navigate to.  Really there is no reason that I cannot use separate tables, and honestly that's an approach that I haven't considered.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a simpler solution that I've overlooked, but the below will work.

Insert a module into your workbook and add this code:

```
Public Sub AddNextPartNumber(ByVal FirstCellInColumn As Range, Optional ByVal PartMask As Variant = "")

  Dim Temp As Variant, x As Long, MaxValueFound(1 To 2) As Variant

'Some error checking
  If PartMask = "" Then
    MsgBox "No part mask supplied", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
  ElseIf Not PartMask Like "*[#]" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid part mask supplied; must end in ""#"".", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
  ElseIf PartMask Like "*[#]*[!#]*[#]" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid part mask supplied; ""#"" must be continuous only.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
  End If

'Get the column of data into an array
  With FirstCellInColumn.Parent
    Temp = .Range(FirstCellInColumn, .Cells(.Rows.Count, FirstCellInColumn.Column).End(xlUp))
  End With

'Search through the array and find the largest matching value
  For x = 1 To UBound(Temp, 1)
    If Temp(x, 1) Like PartMask Then
      If MaxValueFound(1) < Temp(x, 1) Then
        MaxValueFound(1) = Temp(x, 1)
        MaxValueFound(2) = x
      End If
    End If
  Next x

'Output new part number
  If MaxValueFound(2) = 0 Then

    'This part mask doesn't exist, enter one with 0's at the end of the list
    With FirstCellInColumn.Offset(x - 1, 0)
      .Value = Replace(PartMask, "#", 0)
      .Select
    End With

  Else

    'Get the length of the number to output
    Dim NumberMask As String, NumFormatLength As Long
    NumFormatLength = Len(PartMask) - Len(Replace(PartMask, "#", ""))
    NumberMask = String(NumFormatLength, "#")

    'Determine the new part number
    MaxValueFound(1) = Replace(MaxValueFound(1), Replace(PartMask, NumberMask, ""), "")
    MaxValueFound(1) = Replace(PartMask, NumberMask, "") & Format((MaxValueFound(1) * 1) + 1, String(NumFormatLength, "0"))

    'Insert row, add new part number and select new cell
    FirstCellInColumn.Offset(MaxValueFound(2), 0).EntireRow.Insert
    With FirstCellInColumn.Offset(MaxValueFound(2), 0)
      .Value = MaxValueFound(1)
      .Select
    End With

  End If

End Sub
```

Then, for each button, you write the code like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  'this is the code for the [ADD 11-****] button
  AddNextPartNumber Me.Range("B16"), "11-####"

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

  'this is the code for the [ADD 22-****] button
  AddNextPartNumber Me.Range("B16"), "22-####"

End Sub
```

This has been written assuming that inserting a new row onto your sheet won't affect other data and that adding new data to the bottom of the table without inserting a row also won't affect other data.

Assuming you're working with a table, by default it should auto-resize to include new data added to the last row.

Good luck learning the ropes. Hopefully my comments help you understand how what I wrote works.

Comment: WOW! This is great **It 10000% does exactly what I had expected**.  The sheet will end up being relatively "dumb"  so the caveat of affecting other data doesn't bother me - for this purpose.  That code is much more complex than I had originally expected, however it's very elegant in execution.  I really appreciate the comments, and explanation.  This will continue to help me develop my VBA understanding.  The "Error checking" aspect of the code is completely above my head - (I'm going to do some research as to what those are doing).  I  tried to "confuse" / break the sequence - it all works!

Comment: Since you appear so happy with the solution you received please, as a courtesy to @Judge, remember to mark the answer as "Accepted".

Comment: The error checking is using the like operator to see if the format of the provided PartMask breaks any of the assumptions I've made about the part number structure.

You can check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator to learn more.